# Data generation with correlated columns

Tags: gan, finance, vae

I am working on a finance project where i have to work on a model that predicts the short term impact on the bonds market (on the Spreads yield) when a big trade happens based on it's duration, country, either is it a BUY/SELL, Maturity, Size, ....

The problem I am encountring is that I don't have enough of data to train regression models I tested ( **Ranfom forest, XGBoost, NN, KNN**)

I tested classic data generation methods (**GAN, VAE, SMOTE**) but the data I get is really inaccurate.

Especially the impacts on the market data. Because my target columns are : **Impact Spread +1min, +2min, +5min, +30min till +1h**

And the data generation methods i used don't capture the correlation between these impacts ( if Impact +1min is positive and increasing, then +2min, +3min, +5min .. must be positive and increasing too )

**Is there any method to generate synthetic data and that take in count the correlation between columns ?**

Thank you for your help